# Header parameters not added in excel , when i used export plugin in Grails application

Tags: excel, grails

I am facing some problem while export my data with some header parameter using grails. I used below code to add some header parameter for my excel. But it is not appending header in Excel header

```
response.contentType = grailsApplication.config.grails.mime.types[format]           
response.setHeader( "Content-disposition",
                    "attachment; filename=mytext.${extensionfile}")

Map parameters = [
    title: "Configuration Summary", 
    "column.widths": [0.5, 0.4, 0.3,0.3],
    "header.enabled":"enable",
    "header.rows": 3,
    header: [
        ["Total Price", currency,price],
        ["Base Price",currency,baseprice]
    ],
    "header.parameters": [
        ["colspan0": 1,"colspan1": 1, "colspan2":2],  
        ["colspan0": 1, "colspan1": 1, "colspan2":2]
    ]
]

exportService.export( format, response.outputStream, subCat,
                      fields, labels, formatters, parameters)
```

Please help me to add these header parameter in excel.

Comment: Never used the export plugin, but shouldn't `header` be a list of lists of Strings, ie: `["Total Price", 'currency', 'price']` instead of `["Total Price", currency,price]`.

Comment: that's ok, Here currency, price is variable which contains some data. These variable i defined in somewhere else in my code. My problem is these header data is not displayed in excel.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I set the title in the centre & add logo to the pdf?

Answer (score 0):

The values for header.enabled are true/false.